# How can we add pause or mute functionality to the injected RTMP stream?

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

So I am using the [RTMP Injection](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Interactive-Broadcasting/tree/master/Live-Streaming-Injection/Agora-Interactive-Broadcasting-Live-Streaming-Injection-Web-Webpack) sample app. Is there a way to add 'mute' and 'pause' controls to the injected stream?

Answer (score 0):

Read this blog to learn how to implement a live broadcast using RTMP Injection: https://www.agora.io/en/blog/how-to-build-a-live-broadcasting-web-app/.

The [agora-broadcast-client.js](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/digitallysavvy/4ef54c791fe88c668cfe3420d7f6558f/raw/131803648ee9f509729a9d056dba2fd6ab397108/agora-broadcast-client.js) file has the code for toggling the stream (play and pause) as well as muting and unmuting.